# Adding v-bind to dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, dynamic, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue.js (without webpack) but I have a situation where I need to dynamically create a new dom element (like through a button click) but I would like to v-bind the class attribute of the new element. I tried just adding v-bind:class as an attribute but that won't work since vue is unaware of it after vue has loaded the virtual dom. I don't see anyway to non-declaratively add a class binding in code for the element. I tried to force vue to refresh the virtual dom but that didn't really work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code, it sounds like your not understanding how vue works.. use arrays of objects, with a state prop which sets the class.. you dont make the dom yourself.

Comment: You shouldnt create objects outside of vue. You can create objects inside vue.

Comment: I am quite aware of what vue is supposed to do and not do. I was just asking if there was a way to do this. I know it's kind of hacky but it would make it much easier if it were possible. Simple code in the mounted section, using jquery to make it simple is $("#button").on("click", function(){ $("body").append("<div v-bind:class='{active:isActive}'></div>");